# Only audio - no video while recording the meeting using self hosted Jitsi

Tags: webrtc, self-hosting, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I was trying to record the meeting using jibri. In the recorded file, the meeting screen is not recorded but just audio. I can only see the penguin-picture.[The recorded meeting screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds6Vq.jpg)

This is my chrome flag in `nano /etc/jitsi/jibri/jibri.conf`

`chrome { flags = [ "--headless", "--ignore-certificate-errors", "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream", "--start-maximized", "--kiosk", "--enabled", "--disable-infobars", "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required", "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--enable-logging", "--disable-setuid-sandbox" ] }` 
Please let me know if you have any idea

Thanks in advance